# compare some lists in where condition sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have some question in Sqlserver2012. I have a table that contains a filed that save who System Used from this information and separated by **','**, I want to set into parameter the name of Systems and query  the related rows:

```
declare @System nvarchar(50)
set @System ='BPM,SEM'

    SELECT * 
       FROM dbo.tblMeasureCatalog t1
where  (  ( select Upper(value) from dbo.split(t1.System,','))
                         = any( select Upper(value) from dbo.split(@System,',')))
```

`dbo.split` is a function to return systems in separated rows

Comment: Can you provide some sample records for tblMeasureCatalog?

Comment: means you want the string you pass will search in column, but one by one via separate with comma? Can you explain what will be the right and left comes in your query as per your variable value?

Comment: yes exactly but that's order maybe difrent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forgetting for a second that storing delimited lists in a relational database is abhorrent, you can do it using a combination of [`INTERSECT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx) and [`EXISTS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms188336.aspx), for example:

```
DECLARE @System NVARCHAR(50) = 'BPM,SEM';
DECLARE @tblMeasureCatalog TABLE (System VARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT @tblMeasureCatalog VALUES ('BPM,XXX'), ('BPM,SEM'), ('XXX,SEM'), ('XXX,YYY');

SELECT  mc.System
FROM    @tblMeasureCatalog AS mc
WHERE   EXISTS
        (   SELECT  Value
            FROM    dbo.Split(mc.System, ',')
            INTERSECT
            SELECT  Value
            FROM    dbo.Split(@System, ',')
        );
```

Returns

```
System
---------
BPM,XXX
BPM,SEM
XXX,SEM
```

**EDIT**

Based on your question stating "Any" I assumed that you wanted rows where the terms matched any of those provided, based on your comment I now assume you want records where the terms match all. This is a fairly similar approach but you need to use `NOT EXISTS` and `EXCEPT` instead:

Now *all* is still quite ambiguous, for example if you search for "BMP,SEM" should it return a record that is "BPM,SEM,YYY", it does contain all of the searched terms, but it does contain additional terms too. So the approach you need depends on your requirements:

```
DECLARE @System NVARCHAR(50) = 'BPM,SEM,XXX';
DECLARE @tblMeasureCatalog TABLE (System VARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT @tblMeasureCatalog 
VALUES 
    ('BPM,XXX'), ('BPM,SEM'), ('XXX,SEM'), ('XXX,YYY'), 
    ('SEM,BPM'), ('SEM,BPM,XXX'), ('SEM,BPM,XXX,YYY');



-- METHOD 1 - CONTAINS ALL SEARCHED TERMS BUT CAN CONTAIN ADDITIONAL TERMS
SELECT  mc.System
FROM    @tblMeasureCatalog AS mc
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (  
            SELECT  Value
            FROM    dbo.Split(@System, ',')
            EXCEPT
            SELECT  Value
            FROM    dbo.Split(mc.System, ',')
        );


-- METHOD 2 - ONLY CONTAINS ITEMS WITHIN THE SEARCHED TERMS, BUT NOT 
-- NECESSARILY ALL OF THEM  
SELECT  mc.System
FROM    @tblMeasureCatalog AS mc
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (   SELECT  Value
            FROM    dbo.Split(mc.System, ',')
            EXCEPT
            SELECT  Value
            FROM    dbo.Split(@System, ',')
        );

-- METHOD 3 - CONTAINS ALL ITEMS IN THE SEARCHED TERMS, AND NO ADDITIONAL ITEMS
SELECT  mc.System
FROM    @tblMeasureCatalog AS mc
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (   SELECT  Value
            FROM    dbo.Split(@System, ',')
            EXCEPT
            SELECT  Value
            FROM    dbo.Split(mc.System, ',')           
        )
AND     LEN(mc.System) = LEN(@System);
```

Comment: your select must to return only rows that system is 'BPM,SEM' or 'SEM,BPM'

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with your data structure because you are storing lists of things in a comma-delimited list.  SQL has a great data structure for storing lists.  It goes by the name "table".  You should have a junction table with one row per "measure catalog" and "system".

Sometimes, you are stuck with other people's really bad design decisions.  One solution is to use `split()`.  Here is one method:

```
select mc.* 
from dbo.tblMeasureCatalog mc
where exists (select 1
              from dbo.split(t1.System, ',') t1s join
                   dbo.split(@System, ',') ss
                   on upper(t1s.value) = upper(ss.value)
             );
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```
declare @System nvarchar(50)
set @System ='BPM,SEM'

SELECT * from dbo.tblMeasureCatalog t1 inner join  dbo.Split    (@System ,',') B on t1.it=B.items
```